# MVVM with RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, observable, alamofire, rx-swift

I'm trying to understand mvvm + RxSwift but I got some questions.

I'm currently using this approach which I'm not sure if is the right or can be better. How can I do to like grouping the methods, I mean, maybe something like doFirst(loading = true).doNext(getData).doLast(loading = false).catch(apiError) then subscribe to this event? It's possible?

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        viewModel = UsersViewModel(apiService: apiService)
        configureBindings()
    }

    func configureBindings() {

        tableView.delegate = nil
        tableView.dataSource = nil

        viewModel.isLoading.bind(to: loadingView.rx.isAnimating)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        viewModel.models
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "userCell", cellType: UserCell.self)) {(_, _, cell) in
                print("Binding the cell items")
            }.disposed(by: disposeBag)

        tableView.rx.modelSelected(User.self).subscribe(onNext: { value in
            print(value)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)

        viewModel.error.filterNil().subscribe(onNext: { (err) in
            self.tableView.backgroundView = EmptyView(title: "No Users", description: "No users found")
            print("Showing empty view...")
            print(err)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Then in my UsersViewModel:

```
class UsersViewModel {

    var models: Observable<[User]> {
        return modelsVariable.asObservable()
    }

    var isLoading: Observable<Bool> {
        return isLoadingVariable.asObservable()
    }

    var error: Observable<ApiError?> {
        return errorVariable.asObservable()
    }

    private var modelsVariable = BehaviorRelay<[User]>(value: [])
    private var isLoadingVariable = BehaviorRelay<Bool>(value: false)
    private var errorVariable = BehaviorRelay<ApiError?>(value: nil)

    // MARK: - Data Manager
    var apiService: API

    required init(apiService: API) {
        self.apiService = apiService

        isLoadingVariable.accept(true)

        apiService.GET(EndPoints.USER_LIST, type: Several<User>.self)
            .subscribe(onNext: { (model) in
                self.isLoadingVariable.accept(false)
                self.modelsVariable.accept(model.items)
            }, onError: { (err) in
                self.isLoadingVariable.accept(false)
                self.errorVariable.accept(err as? ApiError)
            })
    }
}
```

My 'GET' function just returns a `Observable<Several<User>>.`

Several:

```
struct Several {
    var items: [User]
}
```

Is there any improvements that I can do?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand what you're asking, but if you're concerned about the imperative nature of your `init` method, and want to wrap your API call into a continuous Observable sequence that can be repeated, you could do something like this:

```
class UsersViewModel {

    //...

    var fetchUsersObserver: AnyObserver<Void> {
        return fetchUsersSubject.asObserver()
    }

    //...

    private let fetchUsersSubject = PublishSubject<Void>()        
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    //...

    required init(apiService: API) {
        self.apiService = apiService
        bindFetchUsers()
    }

    private func bindFetchUsers() {
        fetchUsersSubject
            .asObservable()
            .do(onNext: { [weak self] _ in self?.isLoadingVariable.accept(true) })
            .flatMap(self.fetchUsers)
            .do(onNext: { [weak self] _ in self?.isLoadingVariable.accept(false) })
            .bind(to: modelsVariable)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    private func fetchUsers() -> Observable<[User]> {
        return apiService
            .GET(EndPoints.USER_LIST, type: Several<User>.self)
            .map { $0.items }
            .catchError { [weak self] error in
                self?.errorVariable.accept(error as? ApiError)
                return .just([])
            }
    }
}
```

Then, you need only bind a control to this `AnyObserver`, or send it an event manually:

```
func configureBindings() {
    // from a control, such as UIButton
    someButton
        .rx
        .tap
        .bind(to: viewModel.fetchUsersObserver)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    // manually
    viewModel.fetchUsersObserver.onNext(())
}
```

**Footnote 1:** I typically like to make my view models `struct`s so that I don't have to worry about all the `[weak self]` statements.

**Footnote 2:** Notice how the `fetchUsers()` function catches any errors thrown and does not let the error propagate to the outer Observable sequence. This is important because if this outer Observable emits an `error` event, it can never emit another `next` event.